# What can be the Cause of this Error "Communication link failure "?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Respected Experts,

I have just joined a new company.

We have created a replicated database to store the replicated data from MS power Bi. We made a stored procedure to select data from cloud database and insert that in our server. When we are executing our stored procedure to get last 12 months data we are getting this error:

**Executed as user: abcserver\useradmin. Stored Procedure  failed with error:TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 50000)  OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "BI-Server" returned message "Communication link failure". [SQLSTATE 01000](Error 7412).  The step failed.**

The main points of consideration are:

1. Last week It was working perfectly for 12 months data. Just stopped 3 days before.
2. Currently it is successfully working for 3 months data. But we are unable to get more then that.
3. There is not any dramatic change in the database records(means row count)

Can you please guide me what can be the cause for this error. Please help.

I have tried increasing the packet size and connection timeout but does not work.

Thanks

Comment: I'd start with your [remote query timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-remote-query-timeout-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-2017) setting. It sounds like your code is running longer than allowed.[This blog shows it via SSMS](http://zarez.net/?p=3195)

Comment: Thanks for reply scsimon. Actually,  Last week query was running fine for 3 hours. but now its giving error in 1 to 2 hours. we didn't change anything. we just created a new SQL user and I don't know if it has some relation with query execution.

Comment: On the remote server where the query was executed can you check the logs? Maybe your query was a deadlock victim.

Comment: Hello Scsimon, I have checked the whole log there is no deadlock victims. what can be the other issue? thanks

Comment: Well. In the logs it may also show where your SPID was terminated. I’d look there.

Comment: @scsimon - I am facing deadlock errors followed by communication link failure errors. How are they related?